# Replace filtering(?) capacitor on CRT deflection Board

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, crt

I am doing partial recap on CRT monitor Sony PVM 20m2e. (monitor was working, but RGB lines at the top of screen which should be hidden were visible and geometry is not top notch)

I desoldered C584 from deflection board, sadly it's broken (0.15K ESR, 21% Vloss, but capacitance is OK). And my parts supplier did not send the part which I ordered. Now I don't have working 2.2uF 160V electrolytic capacitor at hand, but I have working 4.7uF 250V electrolytic at hand, would it cause problems?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, a red highlight circle may help.

Comment: This is like a nerd's version of "Where's Wally". C580, C582, C583 and C585 are over near DY's connector on the bottom schematic. I can't find C584.

Comment: refresh, and sorry for not highlighting before

Comment: Most probably yes.